# Multiple entries in asp.net form with one submission

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am creating a form which will be used to nominate multiple people from a various teams for an award. There is no limit on the amount of people that could be nominated so it is hard to say how many nominee info I should add to the form. I am curious if there is a way to create a nominee info i.e. Full Name , Email , etc with an option too "add another nominee" where the user could specify more than one person info on the form without submitting multiple forms. **Also user should be able to edit or view the already added nominee info's**

Example:

**About your nominee:**

- Nominee's Name: Steve
- Nominee's email : steve@gmail.com  Nominee's
- Country : drop down list

**add another nominee**

Answer (score 0):

You could create a form (or a modal popup) with a Html Table, an Add button and a Submit Button.

- The Html Table is used to store the nominee information.
- The Add button is used to dynamically add rows in the Html Table, inorder to add new nominee information.
- The Submit button is used to submit the nominees. Use JQuery to loop through the table and post the list of entities to the action method.

More detail information, please check the following links:

[Dynamically add rows to HTML Table in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-add-rows-to-HTML-Table-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

[Pass (Send) List of objects from View to Controller using jQuery AJAX in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Send-List-of-objects-from-View-to-Controller-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)